# How to fix this error StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1 in Asp .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting this error on using api for post,pull,delete data ,but i have a problem in when i update the records i got this error, i can't pass data to api.

> StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent,

Code:

```
public async Task<Boolean> HttpPutString(string url,int id, int qnty)
{
    var jsonString = "{\"qnty\":" + qnty+ "}";
    var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");

    var response = await client.PutAsync(url + id, content);

    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The response is being returned by the server. You need to provide either the source code (preferably) or the documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specific `HTTP verb templates` in backend, such as `[HttpPost]` or other template? 405 means that you specific a wrong `HTTP verb templates`. You can remove the template, or you can change it to `[HttpPut]`.

Comment: @Mohamed Abubakkar, can you accept this answer, or do you have any other issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue make sure you call the api Https, or make sure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30642470)